# Problem to get the link of the default 'post' post type like the orther custom types

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, links, slug, customization

I am trying to **create a paged mosaic list of posts for each post type** (post, custom post types), but I'm having trouble to get the default *'post'* post type to work.

So in the frontpage, I'm using `get_post_type_archive_link()` to return the link post type to go to the archive post type, and it works fine for every custom post type.

**Example:** for the custom post type *'events'*, `get_post_type_archive_link('events')` returns the *'http.//www.site.org/events/'* that is what is expected.
But, for the *'post'* post type, `get_post_type_archive_link('post')` returns the root of the site *'http.//www.site.org/'*. Also I have noticed that the link *'http.//www.site.org/post/'* and *'http.//www.site.org/page/'* does not works this way.

So, **is it possible to list the *'post'* post type in dedicated template like others custom post types (ex. *'http.//www.site.org/post/'*? And if so, how?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the Permalink settings page, you can add your custom permalink structure to make it like you want.

By default, the value is `/%postname%/`
Check Custom structure and correct to `/post/%postname%/`

Save (of course !), it will flush the rewrite rules to get it work correctly.

Comment: I have already tried that and it, and the problem is the same in my case (also tried set permalinks to plain).Also it was not the solution necessary because it put *'/post'* in every link. I think the solution is more connected to change the slug or url rewrite rules, but I am stuck in this problem.

Comment: So, what about create a special page with the permalink slug "posts" and make your special loop to get what you want ? have a look to the WordPress function : add_rewrite_endpoint, that's the better and cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I has trying to use all the standards and recommendation from wordpress, and this should be a simple thing, at least I thought, but didn't find any default function for this…well, I can try that workaround and make a  special page like that. Also the add_rewrite_endpoint can help. Thanks for the help!